# How to set a string with TTL with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I'm looking for a way to do a very [simple TTL](http://redis.io/commands/setex) string in Redis:

So how do I do the equivalent of the following in *StackExchange.Redis*?

```
SETEX lolcat 10 "monorailcat"
```

I found `KeyExpire`, but that means every key I set needs two calls?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oops. Never mind:

`_Redis.StringSet( "lolcat", "monorailcat", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) );`

Comment: Is there a way to MSET multiple strings with TTL?